# Get all the headers of HTTP response and send it back in next HTTP request

Tags: http, go, http-headers

**Go version: go1.8.1 windows/amd64**

Sample code for HTTP request is:

```
func (c *Client) RoundTripSoap12(action string, in, out Message) error {
    fmt.Println("****************************************************************")
    headerFunc := func(r *http.Request) {
        r.Header.Add("Content-Type", fmt.Sprintf("text/xml; charset=utf-8"))
        r.Header.Add("SOAPAction", fmt.Sprintf(action))
        r.Cookies()
    }
    return doRoundTrip(c, headerFunc, in, out)
}

func doRoundTrip(c *Client, setHeaders func(*http.Request), in, out Message) error {
    req := &Envelope{
        EnvelopeAttr: c.Envelope,
        NSAttr:       c.Namespace,
        Header:       c.Header,
        Body:         Body{Message: in},
    }

    if req.EnvelopeAttr == "" {
        req.EnvelopeAttr = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    }
    if req.NSAttr == "" {
        req.NSAttr = c.URL
    }
    var b bytes.Buffer
    err := xml.NewEncoder(&b).Encode(req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    cli := c.Config
    if cli == nil {
        cli = http.DefaultClient
    }
    r, err := http.NewRequest("POST", c.URL, &b)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    setHeaders(r)
    if c.Pre != nil {
        c.Pre(r)
    }
    fmt.Println("*************", r)
    resp, err := cli.Do(r)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error occured is as follows ", err)
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("response headers are: ", resp.Header.Get("sprequestguid"))
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        // read only the first Mb of the body in error case
        limReader := io.LimitReader(resp.Body, 1024*1024)
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(limReader)
        return fmt.Errorf("%q: %q", resp.Status, body)
    }
    return xml.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(out)
```

I will call the `RoundTripSoap12` function on the corresponding HTTP client.
When I send a request for the first time I will be getting some headers in the HTTP response, so these HTTP response headers should be sent as-is in my next HTTP request.

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more detail (and less code)?

Comment: @Volker basically i want to send response headers and reponse cookies in next http request

Comment: Well, net/http provides access to both, the response header and the response cookies, so you can use them them in the next request: The request also has a header. I have to admit I still do not understand the problem. Why not just write the whole response header to the next request? (That would handle cookies as well). Can you describe the problems with cookies a bit more in depth?

Comment: @Volker, okay so problem here is first request is an authentication request which returns headers and cookies for further requests. next requests will be processed only if it contains the cookies and headers returned in first/auth request.... am i clear

Comment: Then just save the headers/cookies for further use and add them to the subsequent requests. I still cannot see a fundamental problem, just some programming needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may be interested in the httputil package and the reverse proxy example provided if you wish to proxy requests transparently:

https://golang.org/src/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go

You can copy the headers from one request to another one fairly easily - the Header is a separate object, if r and rc are http.Requests and you don't mind them sharing a header (you may need to clone instead if you want independent requests):

```
rc.Header = r.Header // note shallow copy
fmt.Println("Headers", r.Header, rc.Header)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/q2KUHa_qiP

Or you can look through keys and values and only copy certain headers, and/or do a clone instead to ensure you share no memory. See the http util package here for examples of this - see the functions cloneHeader and copyHeader inside reverseproxy.go linked above.

Comment: and if i send back reponse cookies in next request?

Comment: Cookies are just headers, you can include them or omit them, what exactly is the problem you're seeing?